# After update compose to 1.3.2 everything not working

Tags: android-studio, android-jetpack-compose

problems screenshot

[image: 1]

update prompt

[image: 2]

works fine if I'll rollback to 1.3.1

Comment: Please take a look at this [page](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-kotlin).

Have you changed the **kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion** and **Kotlin version** in the gradle file according the compose UI version..?

Comment: No, this didn't help. The Kotlin version was set to 1.7.21, I changed it to 1.7.20 and there's no diffrence 

Answer (score 1):

Problem was solved by upgrading to 1.4.0-alpha03 instead of 1.3.2